# In the Service cloud console the home tabs for objects are displayed differently

Tags: url, console, parameters, service, cloud

We have observed some UI changes to the service cloud console especially with the home tabs of the objects with regards to the list views and buttons .
The list views and buttons are following the lightning design system user interface but when we try to access the home tabs with the object prefix url its showing the aloha user interface , this is causing a problem and the experience is inconsistent .

ex:
[image: Console case home page view]

but when I try to access the same page via the external URL by entering /500/o

[image: Console case home page aloha]

I get something like this.

When I select the list view it shows like this

[image: Console case home page semi aloha]

I wanted to know if we need to add any additional url parameters like isdtp=vw with a different value or a new parameter I noticed isWsVw=true.

Answer (score 1):

Just last week I attended a Service Cloud Set-up/Configuration Training Seminar put on by Salesforce local to me in Dallas. Lightning isn't yet supported by the Service Cloud Console. What you're seeing are VisualForce pages that are being loaded with a different stylesheet because they're being loaded through the console.

And yes, they're different than what you'd expect. Salesforce is indeed tweaking the Console's UI. I expect we'll see more changes in the coming months (Safe Harbor, etc).

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: The screenshots attached are not visualforce pages , I understand that salesforce is upgrading the ui to make it aligned with LDS but is there a way to access the screens by passing the right parameter via url ? ex: /500/o which is cases home is displayed with both lds and aloha even , with no notable difference in url params .  is there a way to access only the lds version ?

Comment: @Sid, Nothing to debate here as the Lightning Console isn't GA yet. Do you have MyDomain enabled? If not, you couldn't have lightning pages in your org except in Mobile. When I did the Salesforce Service Cloud Set-up training, we used fresh dev orgs **without** MyDomain. I specifically asked about this to learn how they were getting this look. Because this is all going thru the console, I know of no way to change the navigation it's wrapped in.  It's the same Cases Detail Page from Setup with the Console configuration menu accessed from the links above it.

Comment: @crmprogdev yes, we have MyDomain enabled. Its just causing confusion with our users with the inconsistency in the UI.